# Can I restrict access to podio app after downloaded by client

Tags: podio

I have a niche market that would benefit from having access to some custom Podio applications.  I believe this group of people would pay for this access and that I would enjoy working with them to continue customizing this platform for them.  I need some compensation for this development work and am trying to determine the best way to ensure the clients would pay.

My question is whether there is any way to enable/disable access to a Podio app once downloaded by the client.  I realize I could develop a custom website that logged into Podio to get data for the interface and could push the data back to Podio.  This approach would severely limit what customization the end user could do to the application once deployed.

Is there any way to have the Podio App make an external call that would contact my web server API to determine if the logged in user has access?

Richard

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking about :(
Podio App (as described here: https://podio.com/site/features/podio-apps ) don't make any external calls itself, but it also cant be downloaded. 

Podio mobile apps (https://podio.com/site/features/mobile) are downloadable and installable but work only online and don't store any information and only provide nice way of getting info from Podio API.

Comment: I will sell apps to customers then charge them monthly.  If they don't pay, I need to turn off the apps.  Is there a way to do this?  It looks like deactivate/activate would do this but the APIs don't seem to work